# How could I make Fiddler capture HTTP requests made by my MVC app to my ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that makes request to an ASP.NET Web API using the `System.Net.HttpClient` class. Both the MVC app, i.e. the client, and the ASP.NET Web API, i.e. the server, are hosted in IIS Express by the Visual Studio debugger when I start debugging them.

I would like to have Fiddler capture the requests that are made by my MVC app to the ASP.NET Web API. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

The [Fiddler Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp) addess this exact issue.

There are two parts to this

**1 Set the MVC app to use fiddler** as a proxy either in the web.config

```
<configuration>
 <system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
   <proxy bypassonlocal="false" usesystemdefault="true" />
  </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Or in code: `GlobalProxySelection.Select = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);`

**2 Reference your api by machine name instead of localhost.** This is because .net by default will not use a proxy when referencing something via localhost.

Comment: After several frustrating hours wondering why this wasn't working when it previously had in the same application - you must run visual studio in Administrator mode for this to work

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Framework is hard-coded not to pass traffic to localhost through proxies.  Try using `http://localhost.fiddler:xxxx/`.  This should route your request through fiddler so that it can capture the traffic.  See [Fiddler Documentation on this problem](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost) for more details and a couple other address options.